# set the start and stop frame cv2 python? !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Tags: python, opencv

how to set start and stop frame in cv2 python ?
my initial code:

```
def Deteksi_pergerakan(video_path):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    ret, frame1 = cap.read()
    ret, frame2 = cap.read()


    while cap.isOpened():
        if not ret:
            break

        gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray1, (21, 21), 0)
        gray2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray2, (21, 21), 0)
        frame_diff = cv2.absdiff(gray1, gray2)
        thresh = cv2.threshold(frame_diff, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
        thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        is_moving = False
        luas = 0
        for contour in contours:
            if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 1500:
                luas = cv2.contourArea(contour)
                continue
            else:
                is_moving = True
                luas = cv2.contourArea(contour)
                break

        if is_moving:
            print("Mencit bergerak")
        else:
            print("Mencit diam")

        cv2.drawContours(frame1, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow("Video", frame1)

        frame1 = frame2
        ret, frame2 = cap.read()

        delay = int(1000 / cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
        if cv2.waitKey(delay) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()



video_path = "FST.mp4"
Deteksi_pergerakan(video_path)
```

i changed it to be like this:

```
def Deteksi_pergerakan(video_path, start_frame, end_frame):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, start_frame)

    total_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    print(f"Total Frames: {total_frames}")

    while cap.isOpened():
        if cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) > end_frame or cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) >= total_frames:
            break

        ret, frame1 = cap.read()
        ret, frame2 = cap.read()

        gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray1, (21, 21), 0)
        gray2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray2, (21, 21), 0)
        frame_diff = cv2.absdiff(gray1, gray2)
        thresh = cv2.threshold(frame_diff, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
        thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        is_moving = False
        luas = 0
        for contour in contours:
            if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 1500:
                luas = cv2.contourArea(contour)
                continue
            else:
                is_moving = True
                luas = cv2.contourArea(contour)
                break

        if is_moving:
            print("Mencit bergerak")
        else:
            print("Mencit diam")

        cv2.drawContours(frame1, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow("Video", frame1)

        frame1 = frame2

        delay = int(1000 / cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
        if cv2.waitKey(delay) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


video_path = "FST.mp4"
start_frame = 0 
end_frame = 1392
Deteksi_pergerakan(video_path, start_frame, end_frame)
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\data.py", line 130, in <module>
    Deteksi_pergerakan(video_path, start_frame, end_frame)
  File "c:\Users\data.py", line 86, in Deteksi_pergerakan
    gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Comment: set(CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) is right. if your subsequent read() failed, there's more of an issue. please present a [mre]. most of your code is irrelevant to reproducing the issue.

Comment: you read two frames. why do you not have two `ret` (ret1, ret2) variables? why do you not check them? do you expect that to always succeed? it need not.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do so is to define a frame count variable.
i.e

```py
import cv2

frame_range = [100, 250]  # you want to read frame number 100 to 250

frame_counter = 0

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(...)  # path to your video

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        frame_counter += 1
        if frame_counter is in range(frame_range):
            ... # do something
        else:
            continue
    else:
        break
```